# Passing Forms textboxes values to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, razor

I have the below:

Home Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Transfer()
{
    string path = @Url.Content(webRootPath + "\\SampleData\\TruckDtrSource.json");
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
    }
    return View();
}

public ActionResult FindTruck()
{
    return View("Transfer");
}
```

Transfer.cshtml:

```
<button id="btnTransfer" name="btnTransfer" class="btn btn-success center-block" onclick="FindTruck();">Search</button>

<script>
    function FindTruck() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/FindTruck",
            async: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                ServiceSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: function () {
                return "error";
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

when the user clicks on "btnTransfer", I need to pass the values from the textboxes to my Controller.

Comment: You need to POST your form to pass values to the server.

Answer (score 0):

you should post your form like this example:

```
    function FindTruck(){

  $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/FindTruck",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                Email: $("#Email").val(),
            },
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, data) {

            }
        });

}
```

and in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FindTruck(string Email)
    {
       --------your code----------------
    }
```